# Which JRE is used by EAR / WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, war, ear

Pardon me if its a noob question.

I am developing a Java application using IBM tools. In the project I have used certain classes provided by the IBM JRE.
As per my knowledge, IBM provides its own JDK (different from Sun/Oracle JDK) which is bundled with Websphere server and RAD.

Consider I develop an application using RAD/Websphere and the JRE(contained in IBM's JDK) and deploy the EAR file in the Websphere server.

In this case, will the application look for a JRE in the Websphere server(does it have its own JRE in the first place?) used for deployment or will it use the system JRE?

If it uses system JRE, it will be a cause of concern as most user systems run the Oracle JRE and I have made use of certain classes not present in Oracle JRE.

Continuing in that direction, I feel that a WAR file deployed in Tomcat will use the system JRE (assuming that Tomcat does not have its own JRE). Am I right in this case?

Any clarifications regarding this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a JRE bundled with WebSphere and WebSphere will not use the system JRE.  I believe that [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) also comes with its own JRE, but it can be configured to use another JRE if you prefer.

Note that the IBM JRE is fully compliant with the Java API and programs written to the API will be portable to other JREs.  WebSphere provides its own jar files however and programs using WebSphere APIs may not be portable to a non-WebSphere environment.

Comment: Tomcat does not ship a JRE.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that legally, all JDKs are legally required to contain the same classes per licensing agreements.  This is why Microsoft lost a lawsuit to Sun when it tried to add extensions to the Microsoft VM.

Having said that, I have found that when working with IBM java tools, if you are running on an IBM JRE, you should use the IBM JDK associated with that platform (there is more than one Java platform in the IBM world.)  My experience is that IBM Java doesn't conform to standard Java in subtle ways.

Websphere Application Server is (as far as I know) a Java application itself.  You just deploy your wars and ears and it will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM in production will depend on how your organisation or the client's organisation is laid out (basically who decides which version goes where, the ops team, the tech team, the dev team or somebody else). In the end it should be **one of the non functional requirements of your project**.

All the JVMs out there which are certified follow the spec from Oracle. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ So you have to be really using some internal APIs to cause a portability issue between Hotspot and IBM J9.

Application servers and servlet containers can very often be run with different JDK versions though so be vary of the APIs you use or your app might not start up in the production environment. For example you use the Java 8 features but app server is run with Java 7. The app server won't start your WAR/EAR because it cannot read the class definitions.

Based on the application server itself you cannot make very good deductions as which JVM will be use. It is true that all of the servers have the minimum JVM version that they can be run on but in the end the version can differ. Also it is true that Websphere is most probably run with IBM J9.

One more note. Most of the time the app server or servlet container is run with the JDK rather than just a JRE. For example when you are using JSPs (JSPs are translated to Java code and then compiled to class files) you would need to have the JDK rather than just a JRE for the compilation.